# Is it possible to connect to a running docker container with Winscp?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, winscp, docker-image

I am able to connect to host on which docker system runs. But I cannot find out how to connecting to the docker directly. 
Does anyone know what I need to adjust in WinSCP added to connect? 
Sure, I am able to open by putty, but I want to connect by WinSCP.

Answer (score 8):

You can connect to docker machine with below information:

File protocol: SFTP
Host name: 192.168.99.100 (in most cases)

Username: docker
Password: tcuser

However, I am also investigating how to connect with particular container.

Comment: Thanks, it's works. Just run Docker Quickstart Terminal then use winscp to connect

Comment: @Jaffy Was your investigation done? I need the results.

Answer (score 2):

Docker is a programm you cannot connect to docker directly. If you want to connect with WinSCP into the host docker runs on just use the same settings as for putty because they use the same protokol. if you want to WinSCP directly into an container => don't do it. Instead mount the wanted Folder inside your container to a folder on the hsot and WinSCP to your docker host.